# How to retrieve data from List stored as a field of document/collection in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

[{},{},{},{}] <-- How to retrieve and map this data in widget using ListView.builder() in Flutter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkAmc.png)

[I am trying something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joBBG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are querying `Users` collection Instead of `QuizHistory`. And if you want to access a particular field in a map, you can define a Model class for it or, if you want to do it manually, you can do it as follows:

```
Text(snapshot.data['History'][index]['std'])
```